# java insert record to database in button click event

Tags: java, mysql, database

Can i get a sample of a java mysql database connectivity and inserting records in a button click event?  this is the code i use in the jframe but it does not work it has a error.

```
 private void btnlogActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

     user=txtuser.getText();
      char[] pass=jPasswordField1.getPassword();
             String passString=new String(pass);
            try{                
                **Connection con =createConnection();**             


java.sql.PreparedStatement statement= con.prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO login(username,Password) VALUES ('" + user + "','" + passString + "')");

statement.setString(1,user);
    statement.setString(2,passString);
statement.execute();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exception: "+ e.toString());
            }

public static void main(String args[]) {
 try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Stock?"+
                                   "user=root&password=";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Connection` variable is scoped to your `try/catch` block. You will need to move the declaration outside the block and use:

```
con = createConnection();
```

within the `try/catch` block itself.

Using the `PreparedStatement` placeholders (`?`) will build the correct SQL string and will protect you from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks:

```
PreparedStatement statement = 
   con.prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO login(username, Password) VALUES (?, ?)");
```

Also, use `executeUpdate`  for database write operations. Replace

```
statement.execute();
```

with

```
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `parameter placeholder (?)` when declaring parameters, do not concatenate the variables.

```
String strQuery = "INSERT INTO login(username,Password) VALUES (?,?)";
java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(strQuery);
statement.setString(1,user);
statement.setString(2,passString);
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
private void btnlogActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                       
    user=txtuser.getText();
    char[] pass=jPasswordField1.getPassword();
    String passString=new String(pass);
    try
    {                
        Connection con = createConnection();          
        String strQuery = "INSERT INTO login(username,Password) VALUES (?,?)";
        java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(strQuery);
        statement.setString(1,user);
        statement.setString(2,passString);
        statement.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exception: "+ e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: what do u mean?? please can u edit the above code..

Comment: i get a syntax error at connection con= createConnection();